# TypeScript - typing rest parameters and return values when wrapping a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to create a function that wraps any arbitrary function, but keeps the same type for both the arguments and the result. For instance, this would be wrapping a function - but the types would then become `any`:

```js
// Note that the returned wrappedFn takes the same arguments as fn, and returns
// a value of the same type as the one returned by fn.
function myWrapper(fn: (...args: any[]) => any): (...args: any[]) => any {
  return function wrappedFn(...args: any[]) {
    // ...some arbitrary code goes here
    return fn(...args);
  };
}

function repeatString(str: string, times: number): string {
  return Array(times + 1).join(str);
}

// TS is aware that wrappedRepeatString is a function, but it infers that
// it takes any parameters, rather than a string and a number.
const wrappedRepeatString = myWrapper(repeatString);

// The result of this call is "foofoofoo" (a string), but TS sees it as "any".
const repeatedString = wrappedRepeatString("foo", 3);

// Since repeatedString is of type "any", this compiles, even though
// it'd crash as there's no "toFixed" method on strings.
repeatedString.toFixed();
```

I could type `myWrapper` to take a function which accepts a string and a number as arguments, and returns a number - but if I wanted to use it with a function with different arguments or return types, I'd need to write another one. Ideally I'd be able to write a wrapper in a way that TS would be able to infer that `wrappedFn` (the returned function)'s parameters and return value are the same as those of `fn.

Note that just purely typing the rest param as an array type, such as `...args: string[]`, doesn't work because the arguments might be of different types as well.

Comment: Sorry I don;t understand the question. Could you please provide code example without errors?

Comment: My bad. I've amended the code and given a clearer picture of the problem. (I hope.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic variable to describe the function `fn` and require that the composed function has the same signature.

With the function as the generic, making use of built in utility types `ReturnType<T>` and `Parameters<T>`:

```
function myWrapper<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: F) {
  return function wrappedFn(...args: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> {
    return fn(...args);
  };
}
```

Note that while the composed function has the same arguments and return as `F`, it is not assignable to `F` exactly because functions in javascript are objects, so it is possible that the type `F` includes some arbitrary extra properties which the composed function wouldn't have.

With the `Args` and `Return` type as two separate generics:

```
function myWrapper<Args extends any[], Return>(fn: (...args: Args) => Return) {
  return function wrappedFn(...args: Args): Return {
    return fn(...args);
  };
}
```

Both of those give the desired error on `repeatedString.toFixed()` as the type of `repeatedString` is now `string` instead of `any`.

Comment: Awesome, this does it for me. :) Much appreciated!